# AWS/Android Credentials not authenticating

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying out Amazon's S3 Uploader app for Android and when I put my new credentials in the S3Client constructor the app crashes.

```
private AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY));
```

Are there other requirements aside from making an access key ID and secret key?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?  Did you by chance run an earlier version of these samples?

Answer (score 0):

try this dude i try same code and my app is running fine and one more thing do this code in oncreate() of IntentService

```
 String accessKey = "";
        String secretKey = "";
        String AccessToken="";
    accessKey = Constants.getAWSAccessKey();
            secretKey = Constants.getAWSSecretKey();
            AccessToken = Constants.getAWSAccessToken();

            s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicSessionCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, AccessToken));
```